# How can I add a string to a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to take some http proxies and append them to a list and then test them individually by opening them with urllib but I get the following type error. I have tried wrapping 'proxy' with str() in the test function but that returns another error.

```
proxies = []

with open('working_proxies.txt', 'rb') as working_proxies:
    for proxy in working_proxies:
        proxy.rstrip()
        proxies.append(proxy)

def test(proxy):
    try:
        urllib.urlopen(
            "http://google.com",
            proxies={'http': proxy}
        )
    except IOError:
        print "Connection error! (Check proxy)"
    else:
        working_proxy = True

working_proxy = False
while working_proxy == False:
    myProxy = proxies.pop()
    test(myProxy)
```

My error:

```
Connection error! (Check proxy)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "proxy_hand.py", line 26, in <module>
    test(proxy)
  File "proxy_hand.py", line 16, in test
    proxies={'http': proxy}
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 193, in open
    urltype, proxyhost = splittype(proxy)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1074, in splittype
    match = _typeprog.match(url)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You opened the file with proxies as *binary* here:

```
with open('working_proxies.txt', 'rb') as working_proxies:
```

The `b` in the `'rb'` mode string means you'll be reading binary, e.g. `bytes` objects.

Either open the file in text mode (and perhaps specify a codec other than your system default) or decode your `bytes` objects to `str` using an explicit `bytes.decode()` call:

```
proxies.append(proxy.decode('ascii'))
```

I'd expect ASCII to be sufficient to decode hostnames suitable to be used as proxies.

Note that your `working_proxy` flag won't work; it is not marked as `global` in `test`. Perhaps you want to catch the `IOError` exception *outside* of `test` instead, or move the loop into that function. You'll also need to figure out what you'll do when you run out of proxies (so when none of them work).